# Can I use generic flash tubes for studio strobes?

Tags: flash, strobes, generic-brand

My flash tube in my Elinchrom Style 600RX burned, and I am looking for a new flash tube for it. It is hard to find them in stock anywhere. I was wondering if I can just get another brand, or some generic flash tube of the same wattage — are they standard components?

Comment: Vistek.ca has the 24029 tube in stock, FWIW.

Comment: it has to be inside EU.

Comment: What about [flashtubes.eu](http://www.flashtubes.eu/product_info.php?products_id=49&XTCsid=uq277pp8s3h8147p1fmsa3l302)?

Comment: ooh la lah. just what the doctor ordered. and tehy also ahve the modelling lamp which is also burned.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely yes - of the firing voltage is the same . I tried to find it for the 24029  but no luck . Anyway you don't wanna do this . The pulse duration will be different most likely, also it is not really guaranteed that the power setting will work correctly any more . You have a very nice flash head why would you want other then the original part .